# 'Interaction failed.' Discord slash commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

It worked the first few times I did. It's random. It sometimes works or fails and says 'The Interaction failed'. Mostly failing. Please help.

```
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
@slash.slash(description='Ping.')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Current speed - {round(client.latency * 1000)}')
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the error message `"This Interaction failed."` the library provides a simple solution.

Simply put `await ctx.defer()` at the top of your code, **in your case**:

```py
@slash.slash(description='Ping.')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.defer()
    await ctx.send(f'Current speed - {round(client.latency * 1000)}')
```

If the bot needs more than `3` seconds to give out an answer, the API will return this kind of error. With `ctx.defer()` this is bypassed, and the bot gives out a message.

*Please note that global slash commands take about an hour for any changes to be visible/noticeable. To work around this, you can add `guild_ids=[YourGuildID]` to your code and test it.*

Comment: Are you talking about the discord.py? Because I migrated from discord.py to nextcord. It's a replacement. And your code didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Ala I am indeed talking about discord.py as you tagged it in your question. The defer method is part of the “discord_slash” module you imported so there should not be a problem with “nextcord”. What exactly is not working? Have you used “print” statements? Also: This code is nothing new and works the same as in “discord.py”.